# jenkins slave server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a network issue in that I have 2 geographical locations. Each location has an ESX environment and I have to bridge from the management network to each production network - I cannot use routing. Location A cannot connect to location B's production network. However Location A's management network can connect to Locations B's management network.

I am running Jenkins in location A but I also need to have Jenkins run jobs in Location B's production network. So I was thinking if I could set up a master slave Jenkins server solution. Jenkins Master would be in Location A and Jenkins Slave would be in Location B.

I would like to have all management aspects through one Jenkins server and as the 2 Jenkins servers could communication on the management network, I could have the master initiate jobs on the slave to get run jobs on the production network in Location B.

Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine as long as you can get TCP/IP connectivity to/from the master and slave.  You can set up the slave so that it always communicates with the master on the same port, so if you open that port in the firewall you should be OK.

Take a look at the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) for full details on how to set up slaves.

Comment: perfect - just thought I would run that past someone else.. Thanks very much